# Pyhook event.Injected?

Tags: python, pyhook

Really more of a question here. Based on [pyHook's tutorial](https://sourceforge.net/p/pyhook/wiki/PyHook_Tutorial/), the .HookManager().OnMouseEvent event variable in the function has a .Injected attribute. I couldn't find any information about it, does anyone know what it is? I tried doing

```
event.Injected = '<char to inject>'
```

but it didn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Disclaimer: I'm not expert of this stuff,
I'm just sharing my observations about the [tutorial](https://sourceforge.net/p/pyhook/wiki/PyHook_Tutorial/) and the [documentation](http://pyhook.sourceforge.net/doc_1.5.0/),
in the hope that it will be helpful.

The attributes on `event` are not for you to set manually,
but for your event handlers to read and act upon.

As you can see in the documentation of [KeyboardEvent](http://pyhook.sourceforge.net/doc_1.5.0/pyhook.HookManager.KeyboardEvent-class.html) and [MouseEvent](http://pyhook.sourceforge.net/doc_1.5.0/pyhook.HookManager.MouseEvent-class.html),
the purpose of the `Injected` instance variables is to check if the event was generated programmatically or not.
I think, this means events that your handlers receive from mouse and keyboard activity, will always have this variable `False`.
And there is a way to generate events programmatically,
I imagine for the purpose of testing your handlers.
And the method appear to be [HookManager.KeyboardSwitch](http://pyhook.sourceforge.net/doc_1.5.0/pyhook.HookManager.HookManager-class.html#KeyboardSwitch) and [HookManager.MouseSwitch](http://pyhook.sourceforge.net/doc_1.5.0/pyhook.HookManager.HookManager-class.html#MouseSwitch).

Try this for example. Create a simple program to see the details of some real keyboard events:

```
import pythoncom, pyHook

def OnKeyboardEvent(event):
    print 'MessageName:',event.MessageName
    print 'Message:',event.Message
    print 'Time:',event.Time
    print 'Window:',event.Window
    print 'WindowName:',event.WindowName
    print 'Ascii:', event.Ascii, chr(event.Ascii)
    print 'Key:', event.Key
    print 'KeyID:', event.KeyID
    print 'ScanCode:', event.ScanCode
    print 'Extended:', event.Extended
    print 'Injected:', event.Injected
    print 'Alt', event.Alt
    print 'Transition', event.Transition
    print '---'

    # return True to pass the event to other handlers
    return True

# create a hook manager
hm = pyHook.HookManager()

# watch for key press events
hm.KeyDown = OnKeyboardEvent

# set the hook
hm.HookKeyboard()

# wait forever
pythoncom.PumpMessages()
```

Press a couple of keys and observe the outputs. Press Control-C to terminate the program.

Then, to generate some events programmatically and see what they look like,
try something like this:

```
import pythoncom, pyHook

def OnKeyboardEvent(event):
    # ... same code as in previous sample ...

# create a hook manager
hm = pyHook.HookManager()

# watch for key press events
hm.KeyDown = OnKeyboardEvent

# set the hook
hm.HookKeyboard()

# send keyboard event programmatically
msg = ...       # a value like in the "Message: ..." output in the previous run
vk_code = ...   # a value like in the "KeyID: ..." output in the previous run
scan_code = ... # a value like in the "ScanCode: ..." output in the previous run
ascii = ...     # a value like in the "Ascii: ..." output in the previous run
flags = 0x10    # see http://pyhook.sourceforge.net/doc_1.5.0/pyhook.HookManager-pysrc.html#KeyboardEvent.IsInjected
time = ...      # a value like in the "Time: ..." output in the previous run
hwnd = ...      # a value like in the "Window: ..." output in the previous run
win_name = ...  # a value like in the "WindowName: ..." output in the previous run
hm.KeyboardSwitch(msg, vk_code, scan_code, ascii, flags, time, hwnd, win_name)
```

After you set appropriate values,
and run this program,
you should see "Injected: True" in the output.

I think this is the basic idea, and similarly for mouse events.
Unfortunately I'm not able to test this,
because it seems `pyHook` is a library for Windows OS, which I don't have.

Comment: Thanks :) I had trouble finding any explanation so you really helped me out.

P.S. I can't award the bounty yet, it says I have to wait some time.